# Mod rewire to shorten url but end up with not found error

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My website, interspire shopping cart based, generates link like that:

http://abcd.com/products/Mac-Pro.html (Mac Pro is in Apple Catalog)

Which is very ugly and not seo friendly.

I need it become below using .htaccess mod rewrite only

http://abcd.com/Apple/Mac-Pro.html

I used:

```
 RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

But my server says back:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /products/ was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Help me to shorten the url but not with that error.

Comment: I think you need to make adjustments in your cart software, include the category in your permalink. Using RewriteRule like this ^(.+)\/products\/(.+)$ $1/Apple/$2 will make it work for this product but it will direct all products to the Apple folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch your rule to the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* /index.php?path=$0 [PT]
```

This way the path being requested is silently passed to your index.php script in the query string in a variable called `path`.

Then in your index.php script you can get this value from the variable $_GET['path'] like this:

```
$path_requested = $_GET['path'];
```